# How would it be if a SE site is created on Bangla (=Bengali) language?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, area-51, languages

Bangla (Eng. Bengali) is a language common in Bangladesh and part of India (West Bengal) with a rich history of literature and cultural heritage.

How would it be; if on [AREA-51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) site is opened for discussion about question and answer about Bengali language? The functions like tagging etc. and main portion of the question and answers will be basically written in English (so that everyone can understand and participate) but users will be allowed to quote in Bengali; with an English transcript of pronunciation and an English translation.

Initially the site would include all aspects of Bengali language; such as starting from Literature, riddles, metaphor-cracking through grammar, spelling, etymology, pronunciation, translation etc. to typing softwares, encoding types, problems in encoding, fonts, optical character recognition, etc.

Later on, if the site can survive and cross the beta stage; then further branching can be decided.

Update: The proposal has been submitted at [AREA-51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26739/how-would-it-be-if-a-se-site-is-created-on-bangla-bengali-language)

Comment: It would be nice probably. But you should've spent the time typing this post proposing it in Area51.

Comment: I imagine it'd work about the same as our other language sites (French, German, Japanese, Korean, etc.) do. A proposal in Area 51 is the first step. :)

Comment: However, note that proposals in other languages aren't being accepted now.

Comment: An Indian language proposal was closed. So you can think about Bengali, not discouraging, It's upon you. :)

Comment: If you initiate an at least partially English site about a language, or about a culture/country, it is accepted. It is one of the rare exceptions, although these sites mainly aren't very well-going. Btw, there are far enough Bengali speaker on the world to have a successful Bengali site, but most of them won't ever find the SE on the internet. For example, also the Arabic Language site weren't successful. Good luck to your site!

Comment: @Mesentery Language sites are better accepted, the problem is that you probably didn't advertised it very well. 100 people can already start a new SE site, you only have to find 100 supporters around the SE (which would be probably not very hard). Contact them, and if they help, your site will start. Btw, an arabic language site was started but it was killed in the lack of users.

Comment: @peterh Maybe advertising in the chats will be a good idea.

Comment: @Mesentery Yes, of course on the chat (because communication on the sites are bound to the specific topic). Also I am thinking on start a site about my native language (with much lesser visitors), but I don't think it would survive the private beta phase.

Comment: @Mesentery It is very sad fact that indian language site got closed. But it also seems to me; it didn't get enough attention because it didn't got reached on enthusiasts' hand. because very little people visit/know about SE area51 or what is going on there.

Comment: @peterh I gave link to some chat; but I was blocked (for half an hour) and warned not to post any more off-topic content at a chat room.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused You spammed a chatroom! Not this is the way! Find other Bengali speakers and start a private chatroom with them! You can use the [data SE](http://data.stackexchange.com) to collect them together.

Comment: @peterh Thank for your suggestion. Just visited but i have no idea about how to use that site (data.se)

Comment: @AlwaysConfused Btw, a site about your native language may be boring. It is too trivial. It may be interesting in the case of the languages learned by many, but it is not our case. It may be interesting for the professional speakers of the language, but they are few and not we. I think, a Bengali SO (possibly also other SE sites on Bengali) could be interesting and useful, but the SE doesn't allow it on unclear reasons.

Comment: @peterh Dont know the meaning of SO. what does that mean?

Comment: @AlwaysConfused SO: stackoverflow, SE: stackexchange, can mean all of the sites or the SE Inc company in the US.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused I see you are most active on the Biology SE. Now the sites of the SE sites are so: the largest SE site is the http://stackoverflow.com . All of the others together are 1/3 of its size. The SE has problems with the growing number of the sites, as their (both human and IT) systems aren't enough to maintain them. This may be a real reason, why they make so hard to start new SE sites. They don't want an exploding number of sites. They don't admit it openly; they say always different reasons but the result is always that they simply don't allow a non-English site to start.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused A site about the Bengali language could be allowed, if you can find 100 active supporters.

Comment: @peterh For that, would I have to make a separate site proposal at stackoverflow? (I do not know how to do that) however mathoverflow etc are visible from SE all-sites. Would I just have to write Bengali SO (or Bangla SO)? Right now was trying to rename it Bangla language learners (as per your suggestion "It may be interesting in the case of the languages learned by many,")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1096/discussion-between-always-confused-and-peterh).

Comment: right now for today I'm going to sleep;bye :D

Comment: @Mesentery "Maybe advertising in the chats will be a good idea." but i'm no moderator, so i don't have the privilage to invite someone to a new chatroom. As well on existing chatrooms topics are specified; so if i "advertise" there; it is being considered as spam.

Comment: @Mesentery Off-topic Advertisement is was considered as spam in several SE chatrooms (and they blocked me for half-an hour). Though Bio-SE chatroom didnot said something serious... I'm not sure everyone is taking it well. After all it is 'illegal' due to its off-topic nature.

Comment: @Mesentery The problem is that; it is star (*) -marked, that means it would be deleted if not receives 5 follows within [3 days](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20966/minimum-activity-requirements-for-area-51) !

Comment: @Always Confused I was not knowing it was illegal. Now the only thing I can think of is to put the link in your About me section :)

Comment: @Mesentery Thank you :D :D. I'm doing that very soon.

Comment: @Mesentery You are soo soo soo helpfull!!! if it was wikipedia then I would gift you 10 "barnstar for random act of kindness" in 1 day :P

Comment: You can start a chatroom with any chat SE user. Maybe you shoul know better the systems of the SE.